# Python-generated citygml file failed validation, although identical to example file

Tags: python, xml, lxml

These are two citygml files:

an example file from the citygml website with some changes done to the file manually (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7bUIyq-ZEWY3FRb1hTbEU0SGc/view?usp=sharing)

one generated by my python & lxml code in an attempt to recreate the example file  (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx7bUIyq-ZEWaU1tNU1Wc01XNW8/view?usp=sharing)

When i open the 2 files with notepad ++ and go through them line by line, the python generated file is identical to the example file, **however when I try to validate the python-generated file with the citygml xsd schema it failed, while the example file passed. Why is this the case, since they are identica**l, am I doing something wrong ? (I am new to dealing with xml files)

This is a snippet of my python code, the xml file built using etree (since I cant post more than two links for you to download my code):

```
et = ElementTree(root) cityObjectMember = SubElement(root,'cityObjectMember') luse = SubElement(cityObjectMember, "{" + XMLNamespaces.luse+ "}" +'Landuse') luse.attrib["{" + XMLNamespaces.gml+ "}" +'id'] = 'ID_ground_texture'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't trust your eyes, let the computer compare the files:

```xml
$ diff -u0 landusetest_validated.gml landusetest_cnntbevalidated.gml 
--- landusetest_validated.gml   2015-12-28 14:33:34.437635671 +0100
+++ landusetest_cnntbevalidated.gml     2015-12-28 14:33:34.437635671 +0100
@@ -4,2 +4,2 @@
-    <luse:LandUse gml:id="ID_ground_texture">
-      <gml:name>Simple textured patch</gml:name>
+    <luse:Landuse gml:id="ID_ground_texture">
+      <gml:name>simple textured patch</gml:name>
@@ -26 +26 @@
-    </luse:LandUse>
+    </luse:Landuse>
```

Case does matter.  `Landuse` != `LandUse`.

Comment: Great thanks!! I was stuck for 2 days on this, I will not trust my eyes anymore. I feel so stupid....